# Testing: How flutter test --start-paused work?

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I create a unit test file and I want to launch the command flutter **test in debug mode**.

```
The command > flutter test --start-paused .\test\api_trader_test.dart
outpout the following:
flutter test --start-paused .\test\api_trader_test.dart
00:01 +0: loading C:\projets\commercant.my-cos\prestacos\developpement\prestacos\.\test\api_trader_test.dart                                                                                                        The test process has been started.
You can now connect to it using observatory. To connect, load the following Web site in your browser:
  http://127.0.0.1:55396/a5nXX-epXCs=/
You should first set appropriate breakpoints, **then resume the test in the debugger**.
05:05 +0: loading C:\projets\my-projet\api_trader_test.dart
```

I don't know how to resume ?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, do you know how resume?